# XML parsing as pagination

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have an XML file which i get downloaded from server which is having 50k elements. I need to display those 50k elements in a tableView.
But It consumes more memory.

So i thought is there any XML parser available in swift which allows me kind of pagination like parse 1 to 10 next 10-20 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

All u need is a `SAX` xml parser like `libxml2`. `DOM` parser will not be able to parse the data with 50K elements because `DOM` parsers loads the entire `Document Object Model` into memory to construct the tree and then parses the nodes. Where as SAX parsers parses the xml in chunk.

Unfortunately most of the `SAX` parsers I am aware of are in C. So u have to write the wrapper around them to use it swift project. Good news there are tutorials explaining how to use them.

here are few of the useful links to integrate libxml2 to swift project.

http://redqueencoder.com/wrapping-libxml2-for-swift/
https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html

**EDIT:**

You can make use of `NSXMLParser` as well which is a SAX parser written in Objective-C. You can find loads of tutorials on how to use it with Swift

https://medium.com/@lucascerro/understanding-nsxmlparser-in-swift-xcode-6-3-1-7c96ff6c65bc